# How to write a virtual printer driver for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, printing, virtual

I need to write a "virtual printer driver" for OSX, so that when the user presses Command+P to open the Print dialog, he sees my virtual printer...which will be used to generate files of various types, instead of physically printing to paper.

I'm new to the subject, I looked around a bit but found nothing. Do you have any link or reference to documentation that cover this topic?

Comment: please define "files of various types"! there are several possibilities that could fit your problem.

Comment: Check out my answer, VipRiser is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than writing a driver, consider using the [PDF Services](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11479) feature of OS X print dialogs.  In either the system-wide `/Library/PDF Services` or a user's `~/Library/PDF Services` directory, you can put AppleScripts, Automator workflows, or symlinks/aliases to applications or folders.  Those items will appear in the PDF pop-up menu in the print dialog, and if the user selects the item, a PDF of the file will be placed in the folder or be passed to the application, script, or workflow.

Comment: This is a good solution, in my case, I've to push the file to a HTTP server. How can I achieve it. Also I want to show my custom UI (that will have user authentication etc) when my printer is selected from the list.

Comment: You should open a new question and describe your problem fully.

Comment: I posted a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691092/mac-showing-my-service-in-printers-list

Comment: Is there any information or examples on how to do this and does this work on the latest version of OSX, Mountain Lion?

Comment: Mark, I've updated the link in the reply to point to the current Apple support page for `PDF Services` and, yes, it continues to work on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

#### It is called VipRiser - an extensible virtual PDF printer

There is already a driver that does that. [VipRiser](http://onflapp.wordpress.com/vipriser/) installs a printer that saves to a file. I use it to 'print out' to a file sheet music I buy online. The existing 'Save to PDF' options at the bottom of the printer dialog won't work because the vendor of the music has disabled this function and you must print to a printer.

For the broadest and simplest support for printing to a virtual printer I use [VipRiser](http://onflapp.wordpress.com/vipriser/) rather than using [PDF services](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11479). PDF Services work in some cases but many sites are preventing the use of PDF Services.

Answer (score 1):

In case the printer driver is absolutely needed and the PDF services are not suitable.

The solution is to write your own CUPS driver - both Mac OS and Linux use CUPS for printing, so solution could work for both systems.

The documentation for CUPS provides an instruction on writing a driver (https://www.cups.org/doc/postscript-driver.html), which generally consists of creating:

- A "filter" program that converts the input to printer code and sends it to a printer.
- A PPD file that describes the printer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_Printer_Description)

There's a good tutorial on how to write one in python: https://behind.pretix.eu/2018/01/20/cups-driver/
and provides example open source for driving a FGL printer: https://github.com/pretix/cups-fgl-printers that can be adapted to your needs.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23858581)

Comment: @Gsk  - I've extended the answer based on your feedback,

Comment: @Dharman  - I've extended the answer based on your feedback

Comment: I'm looking for a Brother MFC-L2713DW printer driver for Mac OSX 10.6.8, not supported by brother. Will this allow me to write one?