# How to start writing a virtual printer for Mac OSX?

Tags: macos

I am new to mac OS world. Please suggest me how to start writing for a virtual printer which fulfill the following requirement:

- Software installation process should install it on the target system as a printer driver which should be available for selection from any application installed on the target system.
- Can export image(can be any file type like word document, image etc) to pdf.

Welcome for providing any suggestions like how to go for it(Api's, Frameworks) or any links for proof concept projects/content  which can help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a virtual printer driver for Mac OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273213/how-to-write-a-virtual-printer-driver-for-mac-osx)

Answer (score 1):

OS X comes with PDF printer support built-in.  You don't need to build anything if you select print to PDF in the standard OS X application Print dialog.  You can also easily supply links to specific directories or scripts to run in conjunction with printing to PDF.  Google for `OS X PDF Services`.

Comment: First of all thank u for your response Ned. Now my concern is that i need to intercept a print job, now print job will be send to a server and after modification server will send it back to us and then we should proceed for the print. So i thought of making on virtual printer kind of app that could do that. please provide some idea implement this.

Comment: That's quite a different and bigger question or set of questions, probably beyond the scope of StackOverflow.  But you could try by editing your question to explain in more detail what you really are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research I have found that below link and knowledge of cups(www.cups.org/)will give you great help to create your own custom virtual printer.

Please refer to this link:-
 http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SampleRaster/Listings/sampletopdf_c.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009295-sampletopdf_c-DontLinkElementID_17

Also search for "CUPS-PDF print to pdf" great help guys.