# Mac - Showing my service in printers list

Tags: macos, service, printing, driver

I created a Mac app/service that will be shown in menu bar (and not in dock) that will take care of printing through my cloud server.
What I'm looking is to show this as part of printer list. For example, when a user wants to print a word doc from MSWord, click on Command+P which shows the printer UI where user can select the printer. Now I want to show my app/service as part of the printers list so that the doc can be printed directly using my cloud server.
Is it possible to do such thing. Or any other ideas will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
--satyam.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to figure out how to do this, just researching a way to print to PDF, then pick up the PDF and send that to my own workflow.

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm still searching for the same.

Comment: I found this (havent implemented this yet though): https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Printing/Conceptual/PDF_Workflow/pdfwf_concepts/pdfwf_concepts.html

Comment: @MarkRedman, I've seen that, but I want to show my service/appname  in printer's list and not as PDF workflows.

Comment: Sure, ok will come back if I find anything else, still investigating, this might be a quick win though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to create a device driver. It cannot be achieved using regular application development in Java or Objective C.